# Parallel processing in server applications

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

Since on a server side application the work is done by the server, and since it also needs to serve other request, I would like to know if there are any real benefits of using Parallel processing in server side applications? The way I see it, I think it is usually bad to use parallel-processing? focusing the CPU power only on part of the problem, other requests cannot get server?

If there are advantages, I guess they should be considered only when specific conditions are meat. So, what are some good guidelines of when to use the Parallel class in server applications ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are balancing two concerns: Fast response for a given user, and supporting all users that wish to connect to the server in a given time period.

Before considering parallelism for faster computation for a given user, consider whether precomputation and caching allow you to meet your performance requirements. Perform hotspot analysis and see if there are opportunities to optimize existing code.

If your deployment hardware is a given, observe the CPU load during peak times. If the CPU is busy (rule of thumb 70%+ utilization), parallel computing will be detrimental to both concerns. If the CPU isn't heavily loaded, you might improve response time for a given user without affecting the number of users the server can handle at once (benchmark to be sure).

If you aren't meeting your single-user performance targets and have exhausted options to precalculate and cache (and have analyzed performance hotspots and don't see opportunities to optimize), you can always parallelize workloads that lend themselves to parallel computation if you're willing to upgrade your server(s) as needed so that during peak periods you don't over-tax the CPU.

Answer (score 1):

As with most performance-related questions: it depends on a lot of factors. Things like:

- do you tend to have a lot of requests hitting your server at the same time?
- how much of a typical request's turnaround time is spent waiting on I/O, as opposed to actually exercising the CPU?
- are you able to have multiple instances of your server code sitting behind a load balancer?
- how well does the operation you're looking at get optimized by parallelizing?
- how important is it for the operation you're performing to return an answer to the user faster than it would without parallelism?

In my experience, most of the time for typical request is spent waiting for things like database queries and REST API calls to complete, or loading files from a disk. These are not CPU-intensive operations, and inasmuch as they can be made *concurrent* that can usually be done by simply orchestrating async `Task`s in a concurrent manner, not necessarily using parallel threads.

Also in my experience, most attempts to use the TPL to improve performance of an algorithm end up yielding only marginal performance improvements, whereas other approaches (like using more appropriate data structures, caching, etc.) often yield improvements of orders of magnitude.

And of course if your application isn't going too slow for your needs in the first place then any optimization would count as premature optimization, which you want to avoid.

But if you for some reason find yourself doing a CPU-intensive operation that responds well to parallelism, in a part of your code that absolutely must perform faster than it currently does, then parallel processing is a good choice.